# One-member Array?

Tags: c++, opencv

Here are two lines of C++ code I encountered in OpenCV.

```
const Point* ppt[1] = { rookPoints[0] };
int npt[] = { 20 };
```

What's the difference between that and the following:

```
const Point* ppt = rookPoint[0];
int npt = 20;
```

Does the one-member array have any special advantages over a single variable?

Comment: One idea - in the future it could be expanded to multiple members without changing any other code.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 1-element array means code that uses it does not have to change if the number of elements in the array is increased.

The advantages come in in combination with other techniques, not specifically because of using a 1-element array

For example, given something like

```
int npt[] = {20};
```

subsequent code might do

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(npt)/sizeof(*npt); ++i)
{
      // do something worthwhile with npt[i]
}
```

If, subsequently, the definition of `npt[]` is changed to

```
int npt[] = {20, 30, 40};
```

then the subsequent code can still work as intended.

Whereas, if we stated with `int npt = {20};` the "subsequent code" would need to be rewritten if, at some future time, it needed to be extended to work with an array of 2 or more values.

Obviously it is horses for courses.   Such techniques will be used in designs that are based on having 1 or more values in the array (and by code generators that are given such a design specification).

Comment: Another useful case is typedef-ing one-element arrays to make a type that can be declared on the stack normally and in function prototypes normally, and passed to functions without needing to explicitly use the address of operator; the arrays naturally degrade to pointers to their first (only) element, so it becomes a type that passes around by reference automatically, even in C. GMP uses this technique extensively.

Comment: Your explanation is outstanding! It seems like problem is solved now.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that technique also makes the code hard to understand, e.g. the GMP code looks like it is passing variables by value but actually they are being passed by reference.

Comment: In C or C++, maybe that is harder to understand.   But there are other programming languages - mostly designed to maximise some performance characteristic, such as with numerics and arrays - where all functions/procedures/subprograms/etc have ALL arguments passed by reference.  While I wouldn't suggest that passing by reference is always a performance optimisation, it is not particularly surprising that a library like GMP might be constructed to prefer a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, the difference is obvious.

```
const Point* ppt[1] = { rookPoints[0] };
int npt[] = { 20 };
```

define two arrays while

```
const Point* ppt = rookPoint[0];
int npt = 20;
```

define two objects.

The interesting question is why would one need to define arrays when there is only one element in each of the arrays.

The answer to that question depends on the code that makes use of those variables. Without seeing code that uses them, I have to give the benefit of doubt to the developer and assume that arrays were needed.